# Сompare columns in dataframes and update them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames:

```
a = [{'name': 'AAA'}, {'name': 'BBB'}, {'name': 'BBB'}, {'name': 'CCC'}, {'name': 'DDD'}, {'name': 'EEE'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
b = [{'name': 'AAA='}, {'name': 'BBB='}, {'name': 'DDD='}]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(b)
print(df)
print()
print(df1)
```

[image]

I need to compare values in dataframes in columns name and name2. If the values are equal and the difference is only in the **=** sign, then add it if the value does not contain it.

I need the following result as in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Is the `=` always in the end?

Comment: @mozway - yes, always

Comment: OK, then my first approach is the most straightforward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `=` is always in the end, a simple method could be:

```
# which values of df['name'] are also in df1['name']?
m = df['name'].isin(df1['name'].str.rstrip('='))

# select those and add a "="
df.loc[m, 'name'] += '='
```

Another approach that works with any position of the `=`:

```
s = df1['name'].set_axis(df1['name'].str.replace('=', ''))
df['name'] = df['name'].map(lambda x: s.get(s, x))
```

updated `df`:

```
   name
0  AAA=
1  BBB=
2  BBB=
3   CCC
4  DDD=
5   EEE
```